# Incomplete type with size

Tags: c, incomplete-type

I'm writing a C library, and have a struct that looks (roughly) like:

```
struct Obj {
    char tag,
    union { 
        int i,
        void *v
    } val
};
```

I do not want to expose the internals of this struct through the API, because users do not need to know the implementation and they could change in future versions. Users can interact with the struct via functions in the API.

I used incomplete types in the header for other, larger types in my API, which can only be accessed via pointer by the user. I do not want to restrict users to accessing `Obj` via pointer, as `Obj` will likely only be 16 bytes maximum.

I have not been able to use an incomplete type here, because I do not know of a way to expose only the size of the struct to users, without fields.

My question is:
Is there a way to expose a type with size only in C (no knowledge of the fields in the struct given to user), some other hack to accomplish what I want, or should I implement this in some completely different way?

Please comment if I haven't provided enough details or anything is unclear.

Comment: To give the user the "size", some internals info must be given. To totally hide the structure, even its size must be secret. What is most important to you?

Comment: I'd prefer to hide everything except the size, but I'm not sure if that is possible. I'd rather use an incomplete type (no size, no fields) than expose the fields.

Comment: Aside: it looks like you want a "universal" data/ pointer.  'v' is large enough for all _object_ pointers. Add a 'int (*f)()' if you also want enough room to store function pointers.

Comment: @chux I've simplified here, but my actual struct does include a function pointer as well in the union.

Comment: Then just expose 'struct Obj' and only use 'strict Obj*' in the functions that the user sees.

Comment: Alright, looks like that's my solution then.

Answer (score 1):

The standard pattern for this is to create a function which allocates the struct for the user:

```
struct Obj* obj_new(void) {
  return malloc(sizeof(struct Obj));
}
```

Then just leave the type as incomplete in your public header.

Of course, if you really want to expose only the size, you could just create a function which returns `sizeof(struct Obj)`.  Obviously people can misuse it (e.g., hardcoding the value into their code as an "optimization" to avoid calling that function), but that's not on you.  It is something that is done occasionally, usually to help facilitate inheritance.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I have currently, but was hoping to avoid the user having to access it via only a pointer, because of the small size of my struct.

Comment: If you're expecting it to be used in arrays a lot, you could also create an `struct Obj* obj_newv(size_t n_elems) { return malloc(sizeof(struct Obj) * n_elems); }`.  But if you want people to be able to embed your struct in theirs you have to expose it publicly.